# Define a minimum height when collapsing in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap, I want to set a height when it collapses. Normally I want to keep the collapsible area shown using `.collapse.in` class. So when it collapses it won't set height to zero.

Before collapse:

[image]

After collapse:

[image]

Comment: So you want the box to show nothing inside of it, ie, a flat horizontal line? Also please add your CSS so we can see what your doing.

Comment: It should get some height when it will collapse(small box). I think bootstrap collapse methods ".collapse('show')" can solve this issue. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Flocktome/R6EAW/10/
I actually want to set a height rather that its height 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/1158/

**CSS:**

```
#collapseOne{
    min-height:60px
}
```

**JQ:**

```
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#collapseOne').removeClass('collapse').css({        
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'height': '60px'
    })
})
```

Comment: It's nearly done. :) I need only one tab for this not 3 or 4 tabs. But when it clicked it first got 0 height and then got 60px height. Is there any way to give the height fixed 60px or so.

Comment: Awesome. Now it's perfect. :)

Comment: This is good, but it will cause a "flash" hide when collapsing until the `.collapse` tag is added. It will require CSS to fix that, and in that case, you might as well use the pure CSS solution below from @Max Sychov (edited by me)

Answer (score 3):

Since I need this on multiple elements, I took @dm4web's answer above and created a more generic function that iterates over the elements that have the `.collapse` class and a specified `min-height` and applies the logic to all of them.

HTML Example:

```
<!-- start fully shown, collapse down to 120px !-->
<div id="div1" class="collapse in" style="min-height: 120px;"> ... </div>

<!-- start collapsed at 6em !-->
<div id="div2" class="collapse in collapsed" style="min-height: 6em;"> ... </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(".collapse")
    .filter(function(ix,el){
        // return only the ones with min-height
        return $(el).css("min-height");
    })
    .each(function(ix, el){

        var  $el = $(el)
            // remember the original min-height
            ,minHeight = $el.css("min-height");

        $el.on("hidden.bs.collapse", function(){

            $el.removeClass("collapse")
                .css({
                     "overflow": "hidden"
                    ,"height": minHeight
                })
        });

        // collapse element on load if it has the class .collapsed 
        if ($el.hasClass("collapsed"))
            $el.collapse();
    });
```

Comment: This approach is great, because we can just set `min-height` in css file.

Comment: I tried to take this approach and it works fine when opening and closing, but on first load of the page collapse content is just closed completely, is there a work that would make it for example 160px height when page is loaded?

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević did you try the 2nd HTML example in the answer?  That's exactly what it does: `<div id="div2" class="collapse in collapsed" style="min-height: 160px;"> ... </div>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is, without JS, the example was written on SCSS

```
.collapse{
    display:     block;
    visibility:  visible;
    overflow:    hidden;
    min-height:  60px; // whatever you want here
    height:      0; // if you want it to start collapsed, you need this, else remove this

    &.in{
      height: auto;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome answer, pure SCSS/CSS

Comment: I made a few edits to make it apply more generically